# How can I tell if the sequence re-cycles?

Tags: sequences-and-series

By looking at the general term or the relation between the next few terms of a sequence, sometimes we can guess what characteristics that the sequence has. For example, whether it is alternating, monotonic increasing, arithmetic, geometric etc. My question is how can I tell the sequence is re-cycling by just looking at the formula relating several adjacent terms?

Here is an example. For the sequence $(A_{n +2} = A_{n+1} - A_n)$, with $A_1 = -5$ and $A_2 = -7$, we have

$A_3 = -2, … , A_7 = -5, A_8 = -7, …$. The sequence re-cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence relation
$$\sum_{k=0}^M a_kA_{n+k}=0$$
has its characteristic equation (or polynomial) that is
$$\sum_{k=0}^M a_kx^k=0$$
and then $A_n$ becomes
$$A_n=\sum_{k=0}^M c_k \times {r_k}^n$$
where $r_k$ is the $k$th root of the equation. Therefore, if all the roots have their magnitudes of $1$ (i.e. $|r_k|=1$) then the sequence would cycle.

For example,
$$A_{n+2}-A_{n+1}+A_{n}=0$$
has characteristic equation of
$$x^2-x+1=0$$
of which roots are also roots of
$$x^3+1=0$$
so their magnitudes are $1$. So it cycles.

Comment: In my example, the characteristic equation does fit your description of having roots of magnitude = 1. Can you suggest another example?

Comment: @Mick $A_{n+2}=-A_{n+1}-A_n$ and $A_{n+3}=-A_{n+2}-A_{n+1}-A_n$ can be another simple examples.